# sometimes return the value and somestimes return bool(false)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, multiple-columns

this one return bool(false)

```
function authenticate($user, $pass){
        $sql  = "SELECT * FROM Users ";
        $sql .= " WHERE UniqueUser = \"{$user}\" ";
        $sql .= " AND HashedPass = \"{$pass}\" ";
        $sql .= " LIMIT 1";

        $result = mysqli_query($sql);
        $result_set = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        return !empty($result_set) ? array_shift($result_set) : false;
}
```

if searched with any other database columns like firstname,lastname it return 
the whole row and everything is going well

```
function authenticate($user, $pass){
        $sql  = "SELECT * FROM Users ";
        $sql .= " WHERE LastName= \"{$user}\" ";
        $sql .= " AND HashedPass = \"{$pass}\" ";
        $sql .= " LIMIT 1";

        $result = mysqli_query($sql);
        $result_set = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        return !empty($result_set) ? array_shift($result_set) : false;
}
```

why sometimes some columns doesn't work as expected?

Comment: furnish some of your table datas in DB and functions argument values.

Comment: this is database table [link](http://imgur.com/a/3JGq7) , and this is function arguments : 
$user = "elsayed";
$pass = "there";

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($sql);` you didn't pass your db connection to that, plus you have a variable scope issue. But now you've added that in your new question http://stackoverflow.com/q/39276365/ where this one should have been an edit, not a repost from the other. which was closed.